# NGRX: error callback not reached

Tags: ngrx

I'm dispatching an action when a form is submitted, so then `checkPasswd` is reached:

```
public checkPasswd():void {
    this.store$.dispatch({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN', payload: { username: this.form.value.mail, password: this.form.value.passwd } });
}
```

on `ngOnInit - constructor` I've created this subscription to `Store<IStore>`:

```
private user$: Observable<IUser>;
private userSub: Subscription;

constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>)
{
    this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user).filter(user => user.id != null);
}

ngOnInit():void {
    this.userSub = this.user$.subscribe(
        (user: IUser) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/app']);  (((2)))
        },
        (error: any) => {
            this.addAlert(error.message);  (((1)))
        }
    );
}
```

I'm checking that `(((1)))` is reached when an error occurs. Nevertheless, it's never reached when an error appears.

I'm using efffects:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true })
userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: { error: err } });
        })
);
```

As you can see, in my effect I'm trying to call to my service, and if it gets an error I'm returning `Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: { error: err } });`.

So, after that, this reducer is called and reached:

```
public static USER_LOGIN_FAILED = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN_FAILED`;
    private static userLoginFailed(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }
```

Nevertheless, `(((1)))` is not reached, neither `(((2)))`. So, the call stack seems to not reach my subscription...

Any ideas?

Comment: What's behind `this.user$`?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post. However, `constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>) { this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user).filter(user => user.id != null); }`.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: your select filters out any emission that do not contain a user-id, which I assume would be the case when a login fails - this means that absolutely no data will be emitted beyond this point unless there is a valid user with an id in the store.

```
this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user).filter(user => user.id != null);
```

**Second**: The `store.select` will never emit any errors, since it is a perpetual stream - if errors where emitted, that would break the stream (this is one of the RxJS core-principles: Errors will stop and finalize a stream).

So the behavior seems to be expected to me.

---

How to handle this? - If you are looking to persist errors in your ngrx-store, then you would have to implement a field for that and add a select to get errors and display them - if you do not want to go through the store, you could add an error-alert-handler to the effect directly.

Also have a look at the ngrx-example-app for best-practices: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

Comment: Thanks a lot @olsn. As far I've been able, an `error callback` shouldn't never be set on last subscription (`LoginComponent - this.user$`), isn't it? By other hand, what do you exactly mean with `"error-alert-handler to the effect directly"`. Could I populate the errors using this strategy?

Comment: What I meant was: If you want to display the error to your user, you could do this in the effect by `.catch(err => this.myErrorAlertService.show(err))` - or you send it to the store and have some component subscribe to some error-msg-array (or however you save errors in the store) and display the error there.
--
If you don't plan to display notifications - there is not really the need for all that - just catch the error and return an empty object (basically ending the effect without an action)

Comment: Thanks again. Which is your favorite approach: 1. using an `ErrorAlertService` or 2. using an `Store.errors` subscription.

Comment: It depends on the usecase and on your project requirements: If you want to go 100% strictly by ngrx, when use the store -> this requires some more code though. If you don't need the errors in multiple places and are not super religious about ngrx, then calling some alert-service from the effect is the preferred solution (which also requires less code) - both solutions are technically perfectly fine

Comment: Use an ngrx approach. Where would you dispatch the `ERROR` related actions? On effects?

Comment: in that case it's the result of an effect, yes.

Comment: I've tried it: `.catch((err: any) => {
          this._store$.dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_REDUCER_APPEARS', payload: { msg: err.message } });
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: {} });
        })`. Do you guess what I'm trying? Is this correct?

Comment: don't dispatch within an effect, an effect should only return an action (like you have it already in the code in your question) - the only thing left to do is to handle it properly in a reducer (please look at the example app of the link i posted or the ngrx-documentation)